# copying a postgresql rds changes explain plan

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have two RDS servers used for production and QA.
I've dumped the production db and imported it in the QA one.
As it's the exact same data, one nearly the same hardware, I expected the queries to perform similarly. However, it seems that that imported (QA) db is misbehaving, using sequential scans for most of its queries rather than the indexes (as the production server does).
I've tried to rebuild the indexes, but in vain, postgresql planner insistes on using seq scan rather than index scan.

The sql that is concluded to use the seq scan looks like this:

```
SELECT "emails".* FROM "emails" WHERE "emails"."emailable_type" = 'Type1' AND "emails"."emailable_id" IN (4410398, {many others},137191)
```

Now, since postgresql doesn't have hints, I can't see if the index is performing well. 
So the question is, what makes the postgresql optimizer produce one explain plan in the production db and another in the imported QA one?

Comment: Did you run [VACUUM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html) [ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html) after importing? Also make sure `autovacuum` have been set up ([should be enabled by default](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.PostgreSQL.Autovacuum) on amazon rds instances)

Comment: thx @pozs but that didn't make a difference.